# Simple setInterval timer stalling on tab blur in Safari

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval

I've got a simple timer that I built that works off of a setInterval function. Every 1 second, it increases the value of the timer by 1. When I click off of the tab to a different tab in Safari, it slows down. You can see what I'm talking about in this basic CodePen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxVMRp

This is the basic JS code:

```
function setTimer(){
  var curTime = parseInt($('.timer').text());
  var newTime = curTime+1;
  $('.timer').text(newTime);
}

setInterval(setTimer, 1000);
```

Granted, my timer is a bit more advanced, but you can still see the slow down effect of setInterval in Safari in this basic example. How can I prevent this slow down without having to offload anything to a web worker?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason you're using a `setInterval` here? Probably the reason Safari is slowing down on blur is to prevent tabs from wasting CPU cycles when the user isn't paying attention to them. What could possibly be so important in your code that it needs to be updated every second, even when the user isn't focused on it?

At any rate, you could listen for `onblur` and `onfocus` to pause or restart the timer as necessary. If you need to keep perfect timekeeping for some other purpose there is always `Date.now()`.

Comment: I'm building a timer web app, so exact time keeping is kind of important.It needs to run every second so that the time stays correct, even when the tab isn't focused, considering many people will be using the web app to time work done in browser, and a non-focused tab is going to be a pretty common use case.

Comment: Then like I said, use `onblur` and `onfocus` to track when you need to update the time for a user going in/out of a tab. You should be using system time as an absolute reference point for timing anyway, if you're using only `setInterval` then it's already wildly inaccurate.

Comment: Now here's a thought too... I want the current time to show up in the page's title so that it appears in the tab even when the tab isn't active. I don't believe this method would allow for that, would it?